# POST method not supported when submitting multiple forms through the same JS code. (405)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have multiple forms on the same page that are submitted through the same JavaScript code.

```
<form class="form" id="cancelchallenge" method="POST" action="{{action('ChallengeController@cancelChallenge')}}">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_challengeid" value="462f2e80-8012-11e9-8b02-65a0a3459d7a">
<button type="button" class="btn-submit-cancelchallenge">cancel challenge</button>
</form>

<form class="form" id="cancelchallenge" method="POST" action="{{action('ChallengeController@cancelChallenge')}}">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_challengeid" value="9b9ef9d0-8012-11e9-aa0f-95ff09733e52">
<button type="button" class="btn-submit-cancelchallenge">cancel challenge</button>
</form>
```

*There could be any number of forms all of which will have a unique value for each hidden input.*

Here is my JavaScript code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(".btn-submit-cancelchallenge").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $('#cancelchallenge');
    var cancel_challengeid = $("input[name=cancel_challengeid]").val();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data:{cancel_challengeid:cancel_challengeid},

    success:function(data){
        if(data.successful) {
            toastr.success(data.successful);
        }
    }
    });

});
```

If I submit any given form using the above code it works but it will always only submit the input value - from the first form - regardless of which form I submit.

Okay So I realise I shouldn't be using the same ID's in multiple forms so I change the form ID from:
*id="cancelchallenge"* to *class="cancelchallenge"*
and then update the JS code from:
*var $form = $('#cancelchallenge');* to *var $form = $(this);*
thinking that will allow to submit any given form with the correct input value. However this now results in a 405 error.
"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

My route looks like this:

```
Route::post('cancelChallenge', 'ChallengeController@cancelChallenge');
```

Briefly my controller looks like this:

```
public function cancelChallenge(Request $request)
    {
        //Some validation
        $challenge = Challenge::where(['id' => $request->cancel_challengeid, 
        'player1' => Auth::user()->id])->first();
        //DB::beginTransaction();
        //Update a row in the challenges table
        //Insert a row into the transactions table
        //Update a row in the users table
        //Commit transaction
    }
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(this) - current element.

el.parent() - parent of element.

el.find() - find selector inside element.

```
$('.btn-submit-cancelchallenge').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let $form = $(this).parent();
    let cancel_challengeid = $form.find('input[name=cancel_challengeid]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: {cancel_challengeid: cancel_challengeid},
        success:function(data){
            if(data.successful) {
                toastr.success(data.successful);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Or better:

```
$('.btn-submit-cancelchallenge').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let form = $(this).parent();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            if(data.successful) {
                toastr.success(data.successful);
            }
        }
    });
});
```